# Rails audio_tag

Tags: audio, tags

Hello everyone I am trying to get an audio tag to work in rails. I am using the syntax 
    <%= audio_tag "somesong.mp3", :controls => true %>

However when I utilize this format it throws an error.

This is the output file created by the audio tag.

This is the error that gets thrown in my song folder

## Routing Error

```
No route matches [GET] "/audios/sunshine.ogg"
```

Try running `rake routes` for more information on available routes.

This is my routing table that shows the routes I am using.

> eric@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Musicband/musicband_app$ rake routes
>       contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)          contacts#index  new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)      contacts#new
>        contact PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#update
>          songs GET    /songs(.:format)             songs#index
>                POST   /songs(.:format)             songs#create
>       new_song GET    /songs/new(.:format)         songs#new    edit_song GET    /songs/:id/edit(.:format)    songs#edit
>           song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)         songs#show
>                PUT    /songs/:id(.:format)         songs#update
>                DELETE /songs/:id(.:format)         songs#destroy
>       groupees GET    /groupees(.:format)          groupees#index
>                POST   /groupees(.:format)          groupees#create  new_groupee GET    /groupees/new(.:format)      groupees#new
>   edit_groupee GET    /groupees/:id/edit(.:format) groupees#edit
>        groupee GET    /groupees/:id(.:format)      groupees#show
>                PUT    /groupees/:id(.:format)      groupees#update
>                DELETE /groupees/:id(.:format)      groupees#destroy
>          audio        /audio(.:format)             landing_pages#music
>                       /contact(.:format)           contacts#new
>          about        /about(.:format)             landing_pages#about
>           root        /                            landing_pages#home

I don't know how to fix this audio problem and get it working. Also where is the audio files stored by default? This is kind for a class project that I am trying to get done pretty soon.

So if there is someone out there who knows how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set up the appropriate routes in your `routes.rb` file.

You need to either add `resources :audios` and have an audios controller set up to handle the request or if `audios` is an alias for another controller, set that up accordingly.

--edit--

If you want to serve the audio file through a controller you'll need `send_file` but really I'd recommend just serving static assets from an asset folder instead of through a controller, which just adds overhead. You only need the controller if you're going to add/change sounds.

Read up on the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I think I will try to set up the audios controller since that will probably be the easiest. However my songs controller was supposed be the one that plays the audio. I am still new to rails so I don't really know much about the audio_tag.

Comment: OK I understand what you want to do I'll amend the answer. Please consider an up vote / accepting it if it helps you.

Comment: Well it kind of helped but now I got this error from using the send_file command.                                               <h1>
  ActionController::MissingFile
    in AudiosController#show
</h1>
<pre>Cannot read file audios/sunshine.ogg</pre>


<p><code>Rails.root: /home/eric/Desktop/Musicband/musicband_app</code></p>                                            Um could you tell me how the other option would go? I don't want to rule either option at this point. Would the other option be difficult to implement?                                                           Can't vote up.

Comment: No. You'll need to have at least a basic understanding of serving static assets. Read the link I gave you.

Comment: I figured this one out and am pretty well done on this so I will close it. :) Thanks for your help though. :)